# Can I filter legendary or set items by stats in the Auction House? (fixed in 1.0.4)

Tags: diablo-iii

When I choose a particular legendary (Andariel's Visage), I want to filter these by those which have at least 100 intelligence, is there any way to do that?

[image: I couldn't filter helms down to just Andariel's Visage because it has Attack Speed % which you can't filter on, because it's not present on regular helm items. Also shows a screenshot of the auction house search filter with the fields grayed out.]

UPDATE:  As the title says, this behavior was changed in [patch 1.04](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7029347/7029347#ah).

Comment: Because this limitation was removed in 1.04, vtc for localized.

Comment: @Stephen it would probably be better to update this question to make it clear that this behaviour is now possible, post patch...

Comment: @Stephen this question was useful to a couple thousand people over two months, so it does not deserve to be closed as too localized. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415/134175

Comment: @pixel ~@murgatroid99 It's now a non-existent problem, patched out of existence.  Thus, it was a totally valid question yesterday, but today it's not likely to help anyone out in the future, imo.

Comment: I removed the bits obsoleted by 1.0.4: a bit trivial now, but it's still an applicable question.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5282/can-we-stop-closing-questions-that-have-become-obsolete-as-too-localized

Comment: @Nico Your question was not edited because we wanted to close it; it was edited to keep it relevant to the latest patch.  There's no need to roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of patch 1.04 on 8/21/2012, you can now filter by attributes while looking for a specific legendary item, just like a normal search.

Answer (score 18):

Of course there is! The best way to go about this is to minimize your search. Let's use your Andariel's Visage for  example. You can set the min and max level at 58, the type to Armour>Helmet, Legendary and then the specific stats you are looking for Int,Dex,Str,Socket. Using this you can actually get very specific searches on a single legendary.

Edit:Sorry if it came out wrong. The thing is you cannot search the stats on a specific legendary but limit your search enough that you can find the specific legendary with required stats. A legendary has a specific level so limiting the maximum and minimum level to that of the legendary is where you start. Next we change the item type to legendary. After that we get into the 3 specifics to further limit our search. Let's say i'm a Demon hunter who wants an Andariel's Visage. Well I'm going to make the max and min 58 and item type legendary while searching armour>helms. After this for property 1 I will search for a socket, property 2 Dexterity. The fact that you cannot search for IAS on helm doesn't matter at this point because you will only find Andariel's Visage with dext and a socket now.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I never thought to do something like this, just spent hours searching through specific legendaries looking for a good one.

Comment: The reason of this question is the AH disables all other filters when I choose a legendary item. I'll update my OP with a picture.

Comment: That's why you don't search by name. Just by attributes of the item.

Comment: Are you just throwing empty answers out there? You can't normally search for stats like Attack Speed % in helms. I'm not even sure how the heck you've got 3 upvotes on this non-answer.

Comment: @Nico This is the best answer you will get, it is correct, but just very poorly worded.

Comment: @Nico Editting Post due to character limit